# А что за расширение или настройки VS Code выводит такие подсказки?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Скриншот]

А что за расширение или настройки VS Code выводит такие подсказки?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте расширение JSS snippets for VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Это `inlayHints`, смотрите по `javascript.inlayHints`, именно то, что на скрине `"javascript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "all"`.
Чтобы отображалось и в `typescript`, добавьте еще и `"typescript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "all"`